# Django REST Framework: how to cache the result of SerializerMethodField?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a SerializerMethodField that make some heavy computation. I also use the same method into another SerializerMethodField of the same serializer.
How can I cache the result of the first one, so I run only once the heavy computation?

Comment: another solution is to calculate that data everytime you update an instance (instead of when getting that data) or or periodically update generate that value and store it in db.

Answer (score 2):

Since the computation is common between two methods of the same serializer, you can use the [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) decorator. This will cache the result of the method on the model instance, and the result will persist as long as the instance does.

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class Person(models.Model):

    @cached_property
    def friends(self):
        ...
```

Comment: I took a look to cached_property decorator yet, but the problem is that my method takes a parameter, while cached_property don't want any parameter

Answer (score 1):

With python version 3.8 and above you can now use the built-in caching decorators `@cache` and `@cached_property`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if you are serializing an iterator like a list or QuerySet as the first call for that SerializerMethodField will cache it for all other subsequent objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to use the cached property or cache on the function itself on the `SerializerMethodField` but you can cache the result yourself at the instance level and then use the result if its set i.e.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class WeatherLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    city = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    cached_city = None


    def get_city(self, obj, include_counties=False):
        if self.cached_city:
            return self.cached_city
        
        # Do your expensive calculation and parsing here
        self.cached_city = self.obj['city']
        
        return self.cached_city
```

I'm using a very old version of drf (`djangorestframework==3.9.4`) but this sort of class instance caching can be applied. Another way is to not use `SerializerMethodField` and instead do your parsing and calculations once in `def to_representation(self, obj):` and store the parts that repeat into a variable instead. That would look something like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class WeatherLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    def get_city(self, obj):
        # This could be an expensive calculation this is just an example
        return obj['city']
    
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = super().to_representation(obj)
    
        city = self.get_city(obj)
        
        # Now use your cached value of city where needed
        data['city'] = city
        data['same_city'] = city
        
        return data
```